# Fujifilm XF1 Raf Viewer of Converter - Windows (or even Linux)

Tags: raw, fujifilm

I have a number of RAF files that I want to at least view, or even better convert to JPEG.
I am on Linux (Ubuntu 14). If any software is available for windows that will be great aswell.

What can I do to view these files? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[RAW Therapee](http://rawtherapee.com/) and [darktable](http://www.darktable.org/) are very capable programs for developing RAWs. Both of them can handle recent RAF files and are native in Linux.

[XnView MP](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/) is a decent viewer for viewing them under Linux.

FujiFilm [RAW file converter](http://www.fujifilm.com/support/digital_cameras/software/myfinepix_studio/rfc/win/) works using Wine with some GUI problems.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/script/index.php) for managing & converting [raw](/questions/tagged/raw) formats. It *can* read Fujifilm's RAF format, but *can't* write this file format. See [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) for list of supported formats.

ImageMagick also supports many [manipulative options](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php) for altering color channels, and gamma correction &etc.